# Getting content of split String per line

Tags: java, io, split, fileinputstream

So I have this file:

```
    ------------splitter------------ 
classname: test
class: testing
description: this is a test
------------splitter------------ 
classname: test1
class: testing1
description: this is a test1
------------splitter------------ 
classname: test2
class: testing2
description: this is a test2
```

And I am reading this file with the following:

```
try {
            final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("class.file");
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            String line;
            while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = line.split("------------splitter------------");
   }
        }  catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

How would I get the content of the the all the lines so, classname, class and description? I have tried split[0] which just returns the whole code (without the ---splitter---).

Comment: You don't close your resources!

Comment: Seems like it is an exercise. So I deleted my answer.

Comment: An exercise? I was just seeking for help.

Comment: what is your expected out put?